# Instance object of superclass in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I sort of understand the object chain diagram in Ruby, like in this example:

```
class C

  def initialize
    @vc = 1
  end

  def a_method
    'C#a_method'
  end
end

class D < C
  def initialize
    @vd = 1
    super
  end

end

obj = D.new
```

object `obj` point to his singleton class `#obj` (right direction) and then this singleton class `#obj` point to D, and D point to C (up direction)

my question is, is there an object of class C get created and be part of 
this diagram?

What is the point of this object? can i reference it? is there a point
of referencing it since i can access it's instance variables and
instance methods from `obj`.

Is superclass mostly for providing instance methods only ? which means
we don't usually need to have initialize method and instance variables
in superclass?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with how the compiler will interpret the directives in your example so I'm not sure if an object of class C ever gets actually created although I don't think so. What happens is that class D *inherits* class C's methods and properties. A gross simplification would be saying that when you reference properties or methods of an instance of class D, you are in effect using class D *and* class C.

The usage of inheritance depends entirely on your use case. In some cases it will be advantageous to use the superclass' `initialize` method, in others it won't. Your use case is not really clear, maybe if you let us know what you want to achieve I can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

"my question is, is there an object of class C get created and be part of this diagram?"

Yes, the very moment Ruby interprets:

```
class C
end
```

it creates an object, with an object_id and all.

```
C.object_id  # => 10744340
```

This C object is nothing very special, it is just an instance:

```
C.class # => Class
```

"can i reference it? is there a point of referencing it since i can access it's instance variables and instance methods from obj."
Yes, we just did it twice.

Comment: you mean the object with @vc =1 is created? how do i reference it?